# ERROR: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am converting a SQL Server query to Snowflake.
I receive this error "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated"
I have been testing and have located the error.  I am including the working query below...

```
/****  VESSEL POSITION REPORT *****/
SELECT --PORTCALLS.firma, 
       PORTCALLS.rhvessel AS VesselCode
       ,VESSELS.vsname AS VesselName
      ,PORTCALLS.rhservice AS Service
      ,PORTCALLS.rhreise AS Voyage
      ,PORTCALLS.rhhafen AS PortCode
      ,PORTLKUP.lcname AS PortName
      ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthcode AS TermCode
      ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthname AS Terminal
      ,VOYAGES.rereisenr2 AS AltVoyNum
      ,PORTCALLS.rhcustdecno AS CustVoyNum
      ,VOYAGES.republished AS Published
      ,PORTCALLS.rhstatus AS PortCallStatus
      ,PORTCALLS.rheta AS PortArrival
      ,BERTHCALLS.rbbertharrtime AS BerthArrive
      ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthstarttime AS BerthStart
      ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthendtime AS BerthEnd
      ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthsailtime AS BerthDepart
      ,PORTCALLS.rhetseta AS PortDepart
      ,PORTCALLS.rhseqno AS PortSequence
      ,PORTCALLS.rhstatper AS StatPeriod
      ,PORTCALLS.reise_hafen_id 
      ,PORTCALLS.rhcallid AS PortCallID

      , (select t1.rhetseta 
        from (
            select rhrmanr,rhvessel, max(rhstatper) AS MaxCreated
             from  edb.Softship.reise_hafen as PORTCALLS
             group by rhrmanr,rhvessel
            ) t2
                join edb.Softship.reise_hafen as t1
                on t2.rhrmanr = t1.rhrmanr
                and t2.rhvessel = t1.rhvessel
                and t2.MaxCreated = t1.rhstatper
    WHERE t1.rhreise = 'SAL3048' AND t1.rhseqno = 1 )  AS FirstPortDate
    , (select t1.rhhafen
        from (
            select rhrmanr,rhvessel, max(rhstatper) AS MaxCreated
             from  edb.Softship.reise_hafen as PORTCALLS
             group by rhrmanr,rhvessel
            ) t2
                join edb.Softship.reise_hafen as t1
                on t2.rhrmanr = t1.rhrmanr
                and t2.rhvessel = t1.rhvessel
                and t2.MaxCreated = t1.rhstatper
    WHERE t1.rhreise = 'SAL3048' AND t1.rhseqno = 1 )  AS FirstPort
, (select t1.rhetseta  
        from (
        select rhrmanr,rhvessel, max(rhstatper) AS MaxCreated
        from  edb.Softship.reise_hafen as PORTCALLS
        group by rhrmanr,rhvessel
        ) t2
            join edb.Softship.reise_hafen as t1
            on t2.rhrmanr = t1.rhrmanr
            and t2.rhvessel = t1.rhvessel
            and t2.MaxCreated = t1.rhstatper
    WHERE t1.rhreise = 'SAL3048' AND t1.rhseqno = 2 ) AS SecondPortDate
  FROM edb.softship.reise_hafen AS PORTCALLS -- WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
JOIN edb.softship.lokation AS PORTLKUP
  ON PORTLKUP.firma = 'CRMLS'
AND PORTLKUP.lccode = PORTCALLS.rhhafen
JOIN edb.softship.schiff AS VESSELS
  ON VESSELS.firma = 'CRMLS'
AND VESSELS.vscode = PORTCALLS.rhvessel
JOIN edb.softship.reise AS VOYAGES
  ON VOYAGES.reschiff = PORTCALLS.rhvessel
AND voyages.rereisenr = PORTCALLS.rhreise
AND voyages.resource = 'Voyces'
LEFT JOIN edb.softship.reise_berth AS BERTHCALLS
       ON BERTHCALLS.rbvessel = PORTCALLS.rhvessel
                      AND BERTHCALLS.rbvoyage = PORTCALLS.rhreise
                      AND BERTHCALLS.rbhafen = PORTCALLS.rhhafen
                      AND BERTHCALLS.rbseqno = PORTCALLS.rhseqno
                     --AND BERTHCALLS.rbrmanr = PORTCALLS.rhrmanr
     WHERE PORTCALLS.firma = 'CRMLS'
       AND PORTCALLS.rhreise = 'SAL3048'
```

In the select statement the query works if I hard code 'SAL3048' in the code.
This parameter I want to pull from the main query return.
When I add the table-field into the select of the subquery I receive the error.
"The same hard code is in the WHERE statement but will be commented out when I move to production.

HOW can I pull this field from the main Select portion?

I am stumped.  I thought I had it figured out but I am wrong.

Thank you
Cameron D

Comment: Please format your code using standardised indentations.

Comment: You should move the t2 subquery into a CTE and then do the JOIN logic down in the main query FROM clause, rather than inside the SELECT.  It will be much cleaner looking and will function correctly in Snowflake.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

So following Mike's advise you could write it with a CTE the pulls both the port 1 and port 2 like so:

```
with cte_t2 as (
    select 
        rhrmanr,
        rhvessel, 
        max(rhstatper) AS MaxCreated
    from edb.Softship.reise_hafen
    group by 1, 2
), cte_t1_t2 as (
    select 
        t1.rhetseta,
        t1.rhhafen,
        t1.rhseqno
    from cte_t2 as t2
    join edb.Softship.reise_hafen as t1
        on t2.rhrmanr = t1.rhrmanr
            and t2.rhvessel = t1.rhvessel
            and t2.MaxCreated = t1.rhstatper
    where (t1.rhseqno = 1 or t1.rhseqno = 2)
)

SELECT 
    --PORTCALLS.firma, 
    PORTCALLS.rhvessel AS VesselCode
    ,VESSELS.vsname AS VesselName
    ,PORTCALLS.rhservice AS Service
    ,PORTCALLS.rhreise AS Voyage
    ,PORTCALLS.rhhafen AS PortCode
    ,PORTLKUP.lcname AS PortName
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthcode AS TermCode
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthname AS Terminal
    ,VOYAGES.rereisenr2 AS AltVoyNum
    ,PORTCALLS.rhcustdecno AS CustVoyNum
    ,VOYAGES.republished AS Published
    ,PORTCALLS.rhstatus AS PortCallStatus
    ,PORTCALLS.rheta AS PortArrival
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbbertharrtime AS BerthArrive
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthstarttime AS BerthStart
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthendtime AS BerthEnd
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthsailtime AS BerthDepart
    ,PORTCALLS.rhetseta AS PortDepart
    ,PORTCALLS.rhseqno AS PortSequence
    ,PORTCALLS.rhstatper AS StatPeriod
    ,PORTCALLS.reise_hafen_id 
    ,PORTCALLS.rhcallid AS PortCallID
    ,p1.rhetseta AS FirstPortDate
    ,p1.rhhafen AS FirstPort
    ,p2.rhetseta AS SecondPortDate
FROM edb.softship.reise_hafen AS portcalls 
JOIN edb.softship.lokation AS PORTLKUP
    ON PORTLKUP.firma = 'CRMLS'
        AND PORTLKUP.lccode = portcalls.rhhafen
JOIN edb.softship.schiff AS vessels
    ON vessels.firma = 'CRMLS'
        AND vessels.vscode = portcalls.rhvessel
JOIN edb.softship.reise AS voyages
    ON voyages.reschiff = portcalls.rhvessel
        AND voyages.rereisenr = portcalls.rhreise
        AND voyages.resource = 'Voyces'
LEFT JOIN edb.softship.reise_berth AS berthcalls
    ON berthcalls.rbvessel = portcalls.rhvessel
        AND BERTHCALLS.rbvoyage = PORTCALLS.rhreise
        AND BERTHCALLS.rbhafen = PORTCALLS.rhhafen
        AND BERTHCALLS.rbseqno = PORTCALLS.rhseqno
        --AND BERTHCALLS.rbrmanr = PORTCALLS.rhrmanr
LEFT JOIN cte_t1_t2 as p1
    on p1.rhreise = PORTCALLS.rhreise
        and p1.rhseqno = 1
LEFT JOIN cte_t1_t2 as p2
    on p2.rhreise = PORTCALLS.rhreise
        and p2.rhseqno = 2
WHERE PORTCALLS.firma = 'CRMLS'
       AND PORTCALLS.rhreise = 'SAL3048'
```

OR you could move those CTE's into separate CTE's and/or sub-selects, like:

```
with cte_t2 as (
    select 
        rhrmanr,
        rhvessel, 
        max(rhstatper) AS MaxCreated
    from edb.Softship.reise_hafen
    group by 1, 2
), cte_t1_t2_p1 as (
    select 
        t1.rhetseta,
        t1.rhhafen,
        t1.rhseqno
    from cte_t2 as t2
    join edb.Softship.reise_hafen as t1
        on t2.rhrmanr = t1.rhrmanr
            and t2.rhvessel = t1.rhvessel
            and t2.MaxCreated = t1.rhstatper
    where t1.rhseqno = 1
), cte_t1_t2_p2 as (
    select 
        t1.rhetseta,
        t1.rhhafen,
        t1.rhseqno
    from cte_t2 as t2
    join edb.Softship.reise_hafen as t1
        on t2.rhrmanr = t1.rhrmanr
            and t2.rhvessel = t1.rhvessel
            and t2.MaxCreated = t1.rhstatper
    where t1.rhseqno = 2
)

SELECT 
    --PORTCALLS.firma, 
    PORTCALLS.rhvessel AS VesselCode
    ,VESSELS.vsname AS VesselName
    ,PORTCALLS.rhservice AS Service
    ,PORTCALLS.rhreise AS Voyage
    ,PORTCALLS.rhhafen AS PortCode
    ,PORTLKUP.lcname AS PortName
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthcode AS TermCode
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthname AS Terminal
    ,VOYAGES.rereisenr2 AS AltVoyNum
    ,PORTCALLS.rhcustdecno AS CustVoyNum
    ,VOYAGES.republished AS Published
    ,PORTCALLS.rhstatus AS PortCallStatus
    ,PORTCALLS.rheta AS PortArrival
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbbertharrtime AS BerthArrive
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthstarttime AS BerthStart
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthendtime AS BerthEnd
    ,BERTHCALLS.rbberthsailtime AS BerthDepart
    ,PORTCALLS.rhetseta AS PortDepart
    ,PORTCALLS.rhseqno AS PortSequence
    ,PORTCALLS.rhstatper AS StatPeriod
    ,PORTCALLS.reise_hafen_id 
    ,PORTCALLS.rhcallid AS PortCallID
    ,p1.rhetseta AS FirstPortDate
    ,p1.rhhafen AS FirstPort
    ,p2.rhetseta AS SecondPortDate
FROM edb.softship.reise_hafen AS portcalls 
JOIN edb.softship.lokation AS PORTLKUP
    ON PORTLKUP.firma = 'CRMLS'
        AND PORTLKUP.lccode = portcalls.rhhafen
JOIN edb.softship.schiff AS vessels
    ON vessels.firma = 'CRMLS'
        AND vessels.vscode = portcalls.rhvessel
JOIN edb.softship.reise AS voyages
    ON voyages.reschiff = portcalls.rhvessel
        AND voyages.rereisenr = portcalls.rhreise
        AND voyages.resource = 'Voyces'
LEFT JOIN edb.softship.reise_berth AS berthcalls
    ON berthcalls.rbvessel = portcalls.rhvessel
        AND BERTHCALLS.rbvoyage = PORTCALLS.rhreise
        AND BERTHCALLS.rbhafen = PORTCALLS.rhhafen
        AND BERTHCALLS.rbseqno = PORTCALLS.rhseqno
        --AND BERTHCALLS.rbrmanr = PORTCALLS.rhrmanr
LEFT JOIN cte_t1_t2_p1 as p1
    on p1.rhreise = PORTCALLS.rhreise
LEFT JOIN cte_t1_t2_p2 as p2
    on p2.rhreise = PORTCALLS.rhreise
WHERE PORTCALLS.firma = 'CRMLS'
       AND PORTCALLS.rhreise = 'SAL3048'
```

but the sub-selects in the SELECT region should be avoided, as they are hard for an optimizer to know how to solve them cleanly for a "very large data set" and thus even my unrolling's could be very wrong for your data. It's the classic problem, of to get good performance, you need to know what it's performing..

Comment: Thank you for all the input and examples.  I will do more research on the CTE.